# Product Delete button not responding well

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I got an application in the make here and working on a basket.

[image: Basket]

This is the button (everytime a product gets added it gets a X delete button):

```
for(int i=0;i < products.size(); i++){
            btnDeleteproduct = new JButton("X");
            btnDeleteproduct.setBounds(380, verticalPosition + i * productOffset, 20, 20);
            btnDeleteproduct.setFont(WinkelApplication.FONT_10_BOLD);
            btnDeleteproduct.setName("" + i);
            btnDeleteproduct.addActionListener(this);
            this.add(btnDeleteproduct);
        }
```

productamount is to set up the label aantal with the amount of products:

```
productamount = (int) WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProductAmount(productdelete);
if (event.getSource() == btnDeleteproduct) {
        productamount--;
        lblamount.setText("" + productamount);
        WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.Payment());
        if (productamount < 1) {
         WinkelApplication.getBasket().deleteProduct(productdelete);
        }
}
```

Now the last batch is the deleteProduct method:

```
 public void deleteProduct(Product product) {
            // check if product is allready added to the basket
           if (products.containsKey(product)) {
               products.remove(product);
               WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.Payment());
           }
           if(products.size() == 0){
               WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.CategoryList());
               }
        }
```

Ok I have got two problems with this. 1) The label doesn't respond to setText in the button so it doesn't change if i put it in a other button it does change. 2) if I add more than 1 products i can only delete products from bottom to top, so it only reacts to the last button made and then the following and so on.

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: to begin with, comparing objects with == `if (event.getSource() == btnDeleteproduct)` is a big NO in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point two:

```
for(int i=0;i < products.size(); i++){
        btnDeleteproduct = new JButton("X");
        btnDeleteproduct.setBounds(380, verticalPosition + i * productOffset, 20, 20);
        btnDeleteproduct.setFont(WinkelApplication.FONT_10_BOLD);
        btnDeleteproduct.setName("" + i);
        btnDeleteproduct.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btnDeleteproduct);
    }
```

When creating the delete buttons, you only keep the `btnDeleteproduct` reference. As you overwrite it in each iteration, you only keep the last one for the

```
if (event.getSource() == btnDeleteproduct) {
```

check in your listener.

Solution: Create a listener class that holds the key of the product that you want to delete. Instantitate a different object for each button, and add it as a listener instead of using a single listener for all of them.